# UITableViewDelegate: reduce repeated code by adding default implementations, any better idea?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, runtime

In my iOS project, there are many tableViews.

I want reduce repeated code of `UITableViewDelegate`, by adding default implementations.

I turned the following code,

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.zero
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.zero
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

into

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.zero
    }
}

extension UIViewController{
    @objc func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.zero
    }

    @objc func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

When I need the `tableViewFoot`, just `override` the extension methods.

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate{

    // ...
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 18
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return CustomView()
    }
}
```

**any better idea?**

---

I was intended to `extension UITableViewDelegate`,

```
extension UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.zero
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

It runs, but does not work.

```
extension UITableViewDelegate{
    @objc func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.zero
    }

    @objc func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

After I added `@objc`, Xcode reports:

> @objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes

How to do some improvenment?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of subclassing, you might try to use protocols (given also that Swift is positioned as Protocol Oriented language).

Introduce some kind of protocol, e.g.

```
protocol TableManaging: UITableViewDatasource, UITableViewDelegate {

  associatedType Entry
  var dataSource: [Entry] { get }
}
```

Then add default implementation for it:

```
extension TableManaging {
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }
  ... etc
}
```

Then conform your view controllers to this protocol, override methods where behavior differs from the default one.

Another way would be to make a separate data source/delegate helper class and setting it as `tableView.dataSource/delegate` instead of view controller. (Not giving code examples here, as they might be quite long and depend on your needs.)

Comment: It is close， I need take a think

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the default implementation of UITableView, why not create a custom UITableViewController which has your default settings.

```
class DefaultTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.zero
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.zero
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

When you need a modified version, just create a new controller using the default class:

```
class CustomTableViewController: DefaultTableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 18
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return CustomView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm developing a iPad app. The tableView is in the right half side of the controller. Not controller view in contained ViewController . Just view.